# Get for every day the lastest action performed by a user in a daily log SQL

Tags: sql

I have the following table:

| date | user_id | action |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2023-01-01 | 123 | NULL |
| 2023-01-02 | 123 | a |
| 2023-01-03 | 123 | NULL |
| 2023-01-04 | 123 | b |
| 2023-01-05 | 123 | c |
| 2023-01-06 | 123 | a |
| 2023-01-07 | 123 | NULL |
| 2023-01-02 | 456 | NULL |
| 2023-01-03 | 456 | b |
| 2023-01-04 | 456 | NULL |
| 2023-01-05 | 456 | NULL |

I would like to add a new column that for every day and user_id display the last (non-NULL) action that the user took.

| date | user_id | action | last_action |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2023-01-01 | 123 | NULL | NULL |
| 2023-01-02 | 123 | a | a |
| 2023-01-03 | 123 | NULL | a |
| 2023-01-04 | 123 | b | b |
| 2023-01-05 | 123 | c | c |
| 2023-01-06 | 123 | a | a |
| 2023-01-07 | 123 | NULL | a |
| 2023-01-02 | 456 | NULL | NULL |
| 2023-01-03 | 456 | b | b |
| 2023-01-04 | 456 | NULL | b |
| 2023-01-05 | 456 | NULL | b |

I tried with different window functions but it didn't product the result I wanted.
These are the failed attempt I did:

```
MAX(action) OVER (PARTITION BY user_id ORDER BY date ASC rows between unbounded preceding and current row) AS last_action
```

```
IF(
    action IS NULL,
    MAX(action) OVER (PARTITION BY user_id ORDER BY date ASC rows between unbounded preceding and current row) ,
    action 
  ) AS last_action
```

```
LAST_VALUE(action) OVER (PARTITION BY user_id ORDER BY date ASC rows between unbounded preceding and current row) AS last_action
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question to (re)tag the actual (R)DBMS you are using. [Why does tagging multiple RDBMS products make my question unclear?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/423302)

Comment: Without knowing your RDBMS I am unsure why your attempts failed. In what way did they fail for you?  In some RDBMS, you can specify IGNORE or RESPECT NULLS and since you're not declaring that, I wonder if it is defaulting to the opposite one that you want.

Answer (score 0):

I found out the solution:

IGNORE NULLS statement allows to take the last value ignoring nulls so that you obtain the last value only if it is not null, otherwise the most recent non-null value.

```
SELECT 
    date,
    user_id,
    action,
    LAST_VALUE(action IGNORE NULLS) OVER (PARTITION BY user_id ORDER BY date ASC) AS last_action
FROM your_table
```